# Webcam monitoring software for Windows?

Tags: windows, webcam

I am looking for a webcam software package similar to [AirBeam Pro](http://appologics.com/airbeam), but for Windows.  The goal here is to be able to monitor a webcam that is directly connected to the machine in a minimal interface for direct viewing (in this case it is connected to a second monitor which is a television) and also simultaneously served out for remote consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've looked quite a bit and I found a solution that nearly does the job.  Sadly this does **NOT** have broadcast capability, so I'm not done looking, but this is tiding me over as it provides a semi-minimal viewport for the camera + the ability to record when necessary: [Video Booth](http://download.cnet.com/Video-Booth/3000-2348_4-75332413.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for broadcast software. In which case [Open Broadcaster](https://obsproject.com/index) would be your best bet.

A lot of gamers use it to live stream themselves and their computer screens simultaneously, but in this case you are interested in just the live broadcast capability via your webcam.

Furthermore, there is a plugin for Open Broadcaster called [OBS Remote 1.12](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-remote.19/), which provides a web interface to control your broadcasting from another computer.

Comment: Very interesting option.  Unfortunately it doesn't preview cleanly enough.  After spending about 5 minutes on configuration, the preview window just doesn't resize properly.  The app seems a bit glitchy and just doesn't deliver the live preview and recording option, which is ultimately more important than the streaming itself.